# Vector File Merging fails as string length too long

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector-layer

I am running QGIS 3.18.  I am finding my feet with QGIS.  I am building up maps of my forebears' farms. From death duty and probate documents I have collected the lot numbers of the paddocks. I have then downloaded the corresponding shapefiles from our state lands department.

With properties with acreages in their thousands, I have lots of shapefiles to manage.  Using Vector>Data Management Tools> Merge Vector Layer, I created a file (.qpkg) which represents the freehold acreage for a particular year.  I then tried doing this for the lots representing the leasehold holdings and have run into a problem - field PARCEL_SPI is defined as a string of 10 characters, whereas about 2/3 of the lots I want to merge for the leasehold have a PARCEL_SPI string field containing 11 chars. (whether the lot is leasehold or freehold is irrelevant - I was lucky with the freehold that all of the PARCEL_SPI values were either 9 or 10 characters long.)  The data in PARCEL_SPI is of the format of Lot Number\PPxxxx. This is fine for the case of 34A\PP2846, however gives errors in the case of 118A\PP3618 because it is 11 characters long and the vector file merging process has a field size of 10.

Presumably the easiest way is to define the Qstring for PARCEL_SPI as 11 characters, how do I do this?